# Objective-C initializing a MutableData structure

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsmutabledata

When I use this bit of code:

```
   NSMutableData *stringMutableData = [[_inputMessageField stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I always get the warning:

Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableData *' with an expression of type 'NSData *'

However the code seems to work flawlessly. Could somebody explain to me why this message is showing up and how I would code it properly?

Answer (score 1):

In your code

`[[_inputMessageField stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

returns `NSData *` .

While you are assigning it to MutableData.

*You can change either of them to get no warning*.

```
NSData *stringData  = [[_inputMessageField stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or

```
NSMutableData *stringMutableData = [[[_inputMessageField stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
```